# How to build a Java trade bot

Tags: buy-bitcoins, sell-bitcoins, bots

So my friend is interested in cryptocurrency and I decided to give him a hand, since he wants to start buying and selling coins for profit. I thought I could accomplish this, so I will point out my plan:

1. I will look into GDAX, which from what I understand will be better for us since we will be making several low price transactions.
2. Since GDAX can access Coinbase, I can just use my wallet from there to pull in funds.
3. Once I have registered on both sites, I will start creating the actual Java application.
4. I was thinking of using this API: https://github.com/robevansuk/gdax-java Even though it is a bit confusing for me, I think I can figure out how to do these functions: get market data (to figure out when to sell or buy), get account (obviously), deposit and withdraw from Coinbase, place a new order (for trading)

Now I wanted to ask you a few things on this plan.

1) Do you know of any examples of implementations of this API: https://github.com/robevansuk/gdax-java

2) I am using GDAX for the purpose of security and lower fees, but will withdrawing and depositing for Coinbase cost a fee?

3) I am probably a little blinded, due to my lack of knowledge in the subject. Before I get in this, could you point me into the best way of approaching this plan?

Answer (score 4):

So you want to limit your bot strictly to gdax? There are some libs providing abstraction layers from a specific exchange. One example is

https://github.com/timmolter/XChange

This becomes very helpful once you want to make trades on more than 1 exchange.

Answer (score 0):

1. for examples of uses of this codebase, it might be worth looking at the 'forkers' of the code base and what they're doing with it: https://github.com/irufus/gdax-java/network/members. Also join the gitter channel, theres a growing number of people looking at using the codebase for mostly crypto bots.
2. withdrawing/depositing to GDAX is a 0% fee transaction - its all done within their systems as far as I'm aware so shouldn't cost anything as you're not transacting on the bitcoin network.
3. Join the gitter channel. Link in the README here: https://github.com/irufus/gdax-java/ - this is the origin for the codebase. There's a bunch of us now trying to do stuff with this codebase.